# No Deployment Option under Deployment found in Azure Web App Service

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

Unable to configure Azure Web App Service to work with Github since the Deployment Option is disappeared

I am current following  "Visualize real-time sensor data from your Azure IoT hub by using the Web Apps feature of Azure App Service" (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-live-data-visualization-in-web-apps) to visualize IoT Hub Data.  When I get to 'Upload a web application to be hosted by the web app', it instructs me to configure to work with Github. By going into the web app, click Deployment Options > Choose Source > Local Git Repository, and then click OK. However, I can not find the Deployment Option under Deployment.  Any idea if there is some option that needs to turn on.
See the screenshot https://drive.google.com/file/d/1K5JQrTz60D_jaCdZihZKI3N67z9kV-i6/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The portal has changed, you can find the Local Git Repository under Deployment Center.

[image]